# Accessing Iteration Dates through Visual Studio Online REST API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have been trying to access the start and end dates for an iteration through the Visual Studio Online API but have hit a problem.

When I attempt to access the iteration (using the URL retrieved by `/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/iterations/{parent}&$depth=2`) I receive a 'Node ID is not recognized' error:

```
GET http://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/iterations/{path}/{to}/{leafNode}

// -->

{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF51541: The Node ID is not recognized.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTrackingTreeNodeNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "typeKey": "WorkItemTrackingTreeNodeNotFoundException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3200
}
```

There is no problem retrieving the parent iterations but these don't have start or end dates; only the leaves do and they all give me the same error.

Is there another mechanism for getting this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry it’s taken us so long but in our deployment this week we’ve finally added start and end dates to our APIs. The existing [Classification Nodes API](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes) now has an attribute dictionary that includes the start and end dates for each iteration if they’ve been specified. We’ve also added the ability to Create, modify and delete classification nodes, including setting dates, through the REST API and the documentation will be updated on integrate.visualstudio.com this week.